# Is it ok to ask for "the best" 3rd party plugin for an IDE?

Tags: discussion

I am wondering if it is ok to ask *which 3rd party plugin does the job best with IDE XYZ*?

Currently, I am not in need of such a question (or an answer thereof) but it arose because I "inherited" a delphi application that uses quite a few 3rd party plugins (such as to zip a file, to send it via ftp and the like). Now, if I had been to develop this application from zero, I ask myself, if I could have asked for *the best zip library* for *delphi* on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I would prefer it if you worded it as

> Which 3rd party plugin does ABC with IDE XYZ?

Or even

> Which 3rd party plugin does ABC **well** with IDE XYZ?

The *best* will be the highest voted.

Comment: I agree; I don't think who answers is going to suggest the worst plug-in.

Answer (score 7):

The phrase "does the job best with xyz" is fairly subjective because the best way for you might be bad way for me.

A better way to frame would be mention what plugin you're using & what is expected from that plugin.

Comment: I understand the subjective implications using *the best*, but that's only part of why I asked. I was wondering if questions that specifically ask for naming a vendor are welcomed.

Comment: They should be fine, I'd drop a note mentioning why you require from a specific vendor so that people understand.